# Send numbers bigger than 256 by SPI

Tags: spi

How can i send numbers like 300 or 1024 ?

I'm using the recommendation of the atmel's manual.

```
void SpiTransmitir(unsigned char data)
{
   SPDR = data;
   while(!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF)));//{Serial.println("While");}
}
```

I imagined that one bit shift could be the solution, but it still fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send two bytes - a high byte and a low byte.

There are two things you need to know with SPI:

1. You must wait for one byte to finish transmitting before you send the next
2. The whole transaction needs to be wrapped with a digital *chip select* signal.

So you have:

1. Chip Select idles HIGH
2. You lower Chip Select
3. You send one byte
4. You send the other byte
5. You raise chip select

At the receiver you:

1. Wait for chip select to go low
2. Receive one byte
3. Receive a second byte
4. Chip Select rises
5. You combine the two bytes together into one integer.

Comment: Can i use the arduino's functions  lowByte() highByte()?

Comment: You can, yes.  Or just do it manually with `>> 8` and `& 0xFF`

Answer (score 0):

Try to join the numbers as follows:

```
#define NUMERO 342

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println(NUMERO, BIN); // Mostra valor do número em binário

  uint8_t MSB = 0, LSB = 0; // Dois números de 8 bits

  uint16_t junta = 0; // Valor junto em 16 bits

  MSB = NUMERO >> 4;
  LSB = NUMERO << 4;


  junta = (MSB << 4) | (LSB >> 4) ;

  Serial.println(junta, BIN);
}

void loop() {}
```